# Unexpected Decoding of = in Controller

Tags: encoding, playframework

From the front-end, I'm performing a jQuery `POST` with the following data:

`[{name: "Kevin", age: 100, favoriteOperator:"="}]`

This POST hits `/sample` URL.

In my controller, I read in the POST's body using:

```
  def submit = Action { implicit request => 
 val maybeRequestAsFormUrlEncoded: Option[Map[String, Seq[String]]] =  
                        request.body.asFormUrlEncoded
```

Printing out map shows:
 `Map([{"name" : "Kevin", "age" : 100, "favoriteOperator" :" -> List("}])`

Why is my `favoriteOperator` showing up as `" -> List("` rather than `"="`?

Comment: Maybe you need to URL-encode the `=`-character? Does it work if you use `%3D` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Quite sure `asFormUrlEncoded` expects input like:

```
queryString=abc,def
anotherQueryString=blabla
```

which then is transformed into your map as:

```
Map("queryString" -> List("abc", "def"), "anotherQueryString" -> List("blabla"))
```

(I'm actually not so sure if `abc,def` and `blabla` really are deserialized into a list, that idea just comes because you get a list in your sample). Anyways, important is that `asFormUrlEncoded` expects **key-value** pairs **separated by a = sign**, that's why your string is taken apart like that. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encoding.

You might want to look into Json deserializers in play, as your request has a Json format:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson